# Using a string to create a function name

Tags: r

Does anyone know a way to return three dataframes with similar names without copying and pasting?

Basically a way to write this:

```
  mean_dbh <- aggregate(dbh ~ date + plot, data, mean)
  mean_agb <- aggregate(agb ~ date + plot, data, mean)
  mean_ba <- aggregate(ba ~ date + plot, data, mean)
```

something like

```
for (val in c('dbh','agb','ba)){
  mean_'val' <- aggregate(val ~ date + plot, data, mean)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could try this. First, generate one data frame with all variables and then select each variable for a new file:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- aggregate(cbind(dbh,agb,ba)  ~ date + plot, data, mean)
val <- c('dbh','agb','ba')
for (i in seq(length(val))){
  assign(paste0('mean_', val[i]), df %>% select(date, plot, val[i]))}
```

Comment: MrFlick gave valuable advice, but also I really wanted to know function paste0, it's useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In R we try to avoid creating variables with values stored in the variable names. It makes working with those data.frames much more difficult in general. It's better to work with related values in a list. Here's an alternate way to tackle your problem

```
vars <- c("dbh","agb","ba")
mean_var <- vars |>
  sapply(function(x) reformulate(c("date","plot"), response = x)) |>
  lapply(function(x) aggregate(x, data, mean)) |>
  setNames(vars)
```

This will create a list and you can extract the values with

```
mean_var$dbh
mean_var$agb
mean_var$ba
# or...
mean_var[[1]]
mean_var[[2]]
mean_var[[3]]
```